How do I create a highly conductive vapor cloud?
I'm working on a project that requires that I create an electrically conductive gas cloud that can conduct voltages as low as 1.5v from a regular double A battery. I've been looking into using mecury vapor since it's a metal and good conductor while also having a low boiling point.
What do you think of this approach and are there any other suggestions? Or how do I achieve this?

See "Can Gases conduct Electricity?".

Perhaps you can ionize the gas in a discharge tube?

Avoiding making a toxic cloud of mercury would be a good idea. What are you really trying to accomplish? 1.5V isn’t enough for pretty much anything.

@JonCuster I'm attempting to create a conductive path across leads in a regular circuit without using a solid or liquid conductor. I mean circuits powered by 9V or 3V batteries.

Well, no vapor is going to work then. Your V/cm are way too small (given circuit board tolerances) to ionize a vapor or initiate surface flashover.

@JonCuster So what alternative is there to achieve this in the gas form?

Well, I don’t know exactly what you are trying to do here. Explain that and there may well be options.

@JonCuster I simply want to short a circuit by means of a conductive gas cloud around it.

That is the approach to solving a problem you have chosen, not the problem itself. There are always more ways to accomplish things. Why do you want to short a circuit and for what reasons should it be shorted?

@JonCuster I simply want to short a circuit without physical contact with the circuit itself, and no preinstalled discharge circuitry.

A vacuum tube might be what you are after.

@mmesser314 No it's not, I need it to operate at normal ambient conditions.

Under what conditions must the circuit be shorted. What conditions can it not be shorted. Why doesn’t some sensor and a relay suffice? Regardless, how you want to do it isn’t going to work.

@JonCuster It doesn't matter Jon, it doesn't have to be reversible, all I'm looking for is any means I can short a low voltage circuit remotely without physically touching it. Can you help me with any recommendations?

Since I still don’t know why and under what conditions, no. You need to step back and think more broadly. But that is an engineering problem for you to sort out.

If you have some money to spend, possibilities open up that wouldn't otherwise be available. E.G. Can you afford a high power laser? You could vaporize something to create a momentary plasma between two wires. Without more info, we can't really help.

There are solid state device you can short by switching a voltage. Is that acceptable? If not, why? If you are going to be mysterious about it, there really isn't much point to us trying.

There are no conductive gasses. That's not just coincidental. The idea of "conductivity" and the idea of "gas" are not compatible with each other.

cross-posted https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/182967/how-do-i-create-a-highly-conductive-vapor-cloud

Atoms of metallic materials like mercury in a vapor are not a metal. A metal is a material where electrons are not bound to individual atoms. Rather they spread out and move freely in the material.
As the comments point out, gases are generally insulators unless voltages are high enough to ionize them. Ionizing them creates charges that can be moved by electric fields.
You could cheat. You could create ions (with would take a high voltage somewhere) and add them to air. The ions would bring some conductivity to air.
One way to do that is to burn a candle. Flames have ions. Some remain in the smoke.
Another way might be to use an air purifier. See What are ionizers and other ozone generating air cleaners? You probably won't get much conductivity.

In that case, is it possible to ionize gases at fairly room temperature? I mean can a plasma (ionized gas) exist at a normal, cool to touch temperature?

Yes you can. But the ions very quickly recombine. For example, static electricity makes a spark. The spark is ionized air. As soon as the spark is gone, so are almost all the ions. A flame contains ions. They last as long as the flame is hot. If you stick two wires in a flame, you might find that a 1.5 V battery generates a reasonable current. Stick the wires above the flame and you will find much less current.

Therefore no stable plasma can be created without high temperature or high voltage?

I don't think so. + and - charges attract each other very strongly. You either need very high temperatures to knock atoms together violently enough to knock them apart, or very high voltages to generate very high electric fields that create forces strong enough to pull charges off atoms.

@TechDroid, This answer says, "Gases are generally insulators unless voltages are high enough to ionize them." ...And, when the gas is ionized, we don't call it "gas" anymore. We call it a plasma.
